# trying to reproduce "Unknown test operator" on HP-UX

Tags: shell-script, wc

HP-UX **** B.11.31 U ia64 ***** unlimited-user license

```
 LINE_COUNT=`wc -l ${LOG_DIR}/file_transaction.log`
  if [ ${LINE_COUNT:-"0"} -ge 10000 ]
  then
    mv ${LOG_DIR}/file_transaction.log ${LOG_DIR}/file_transaction.${DATE_STAMP}.log
  fi
```

the above code generates

```
/opt/***/***/bin/***_file_mgmt_out.ksh[239]: /var/opt/***/****/log/file_transaction.log: unknown test operator
```

I am unable to reproduce this error in the below code

```
LINE_COUNT=1234
  if [ ${LINE_COUNT:-"0"} -ge 1000 ]
  then
    echo "line count is greater than thousand"
    else
    echo "line count is lesser than thousand"
  fi
```

I've tried executing the above code with LINE_COUNT=990 and LINE_COUNT=""

Answer (score 3):

If you use wc -l as you did with a file as argument you get something like

```
line-count file-name
```

which is an inappropriate format for the test operator.

If you want the line count alone let wc read the file from standard input...

```
LINE_COUNT=$( wc -l < "${LOG_DIR}/file_transaction.log" )
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the output of `wc -l ${LOG_DIR}/file_transaction.log`. It will be of the form:

```
1234 .../file_transaction.log
```

Instead, use:

```
wc -l < ${LOG_DIR}/file_transaction.log
```